# * What went wrong: Could not determine java version from '15.0.1'

Tags: java, cordova, ionic-framework, compiler-errors

I tried to run `sudo ionic cordova build android` on my mac and keep getting.

> What went wrong:
> Could not determine java version from '15.0.1'.

as an error.

I've set my Path and environment variables as

`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
`export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH.`

Comment: is your JAVA_HOME variable literally `/usr/libexec/java_home  -v 1.8` instead of the evaluated value of it?

Comment: Yes, I have java 15.0.1 downloaded too so to direct it to that particular version I have set it literally to " /usr/libexec/java_home  -v 1.8 "

Comment: well, that is not what JAVA_HOME is supposed to be, it should point to the java home location, it should not itself be a command. It should be something like `/some/path/java/jdk1.8`.

Comment: so what would that look like

Comment: You may also need to have the PATH set to the location of the java binaries if you have multiple java's.